# How to get a list of days from an interval of timestamps

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that would give me an array of days that exists between two timestamps.

For example

```
getDays(int startTimestamp,int stopTimestamp);
```

the output would be

```
2011-11-05
2011-11-06
2011-11-07
```

Is there anyway of doing this in a clean way without having to do some heavy algo ?

I'm not familiar with C++ so I just want to make sure there is no function that could do this for me before I start writting a big function.

Cheers

Comment: This sounds like a fun little problem

Comment: I'd assume they are something like Unix timestamps (milliseconds from Epoch).

Comment: Yes they are timestamps obviously

Comment: assumptions are the root of all evil. Shall the function really print the dates? Sounds a bit like homework for me...

Comment: @Pate well we've figured that - what R. Martinho Fernandes is saying that what is the format of those ints.

Comment: This is not a homework, I'm not going to print the dates this is just a way of explain the problem...

Comment: @Nim sorry if there was a confusion but I meant unix timestamps.

Comment: Wow, not a single Boost answer yet? :)

Comment: @Kos: who needs boost when we have C++11 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a while loop

```
std::vector<std::string> dateList;
while ( startTimestamp < stopTimestamp )
{

    //Use strftime to convert startTimestamp to your format 
    // append to dateList
    //increment startTimestamp by 1 day depending on what unit it is
}
```

[strftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) documenation.  If your units were time_t this is a specific example

```
std::vector<std::string> getDays(time_t startTimestamp,time_t stopTimestamp)
{
    std::vector<std::string> dateList;
    char buffer[256];

    while ( startTimestamp < stopTimestamp )
    {
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        timeinfo = localtime ( &startTimestamp );

        strftime (buffer,256,"%Y-%m-%d",timeinfo);

        dateList.push_back( buffer );

        startTimestamp += 24 * 60 * 60;
    }

    return dateList;
}
```

Comment: This will skip the last day if `startTimestamp` is at 23:59:59 of some day and `stopTimestamp` is at 00:00:01 of some other day. I don't know if the OP cares about that.

Comment: localtime is only not thread safe... :) I am assuming the OP will read some documentation before he cuts/pastes my code

Comment: You may have [a bug](https://ideone.com/KKlLr), if the date range includes March 13, 2011 in the USA.

Answer (score 3):

From reading the docs, this should work on C++0x (but I haven't got a compliant compiler handy to test it myself)<sup>1</sup>:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

template <typename Clock>
    void dayList(Clock from, Clock till)
{
    for (Clock day=from; day<=till; day += hours(24))
    {
        std::time_t day_c = system_clock::to_time_t(day);
        std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&day_c), "%Y-%M-%D") << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    time_point<system_clock> 
        from = system_clock::now(),
        till = from + hours(190000);

    dayList(from, till);
}
```

<sup>1</sup> **Edit** *[This](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/49/04709324/DOWNLOAD/932445_Bonus%20Chapter%202.pdf) suggests that you'd need to have VS2010 (or maybe gcc4.7?)*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print both days when the start is "2011/11/18 23:59:59" and the end is "2011/11/19 00:00:01", you can start by aligning `startTimestamp` to midnight of its day.

A day has `24*60*60` seconds in it, so you would do:

```
int const seconds_per_day = 24 * 60 * 60;
int alignedStart = startTimestamp - startTimestamp % seconds_per_day;
```

Then you loop from that `alignedStart` until you reach or go past the `stopTimestamp`, advancing `seconds_per_day` each time.

Answer (score 0):

A different implementation, transforming counting iterators using a lambda function:

```
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> getDays(time_t start, time_t end) {
  std::vector<std::string> ret;
  std::transform(boost::make_counting_iterator<unsigned>(start/(24*3600)),
                 boost::make_counting_iterator<unsigned>(end/(24*3600)),
                 std::back_inserter(ret),
                 [](unsigned day) {
    return to_iso_extended_string(boost::posix_time::from_time_t(day*3600*24)).substr(0,10);
  });
  return ret;
}
```

Tested with:

```
int main() {
  const std::vector<std::string> days = getDays(0, time(NULL));
  std::copy(days.begin(), days.end(), 
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```